# Clarification of a statement in Thomason-Trobaugh.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

See the following paragraph from 'Higher Algebraic K-Theory of Schemes'.

[image]

What exactly is an $\mathcal{O}_X$-module according to his convention? Is it the same as the one in Hartshorne? From reading ahead, it does seem to be the case. Note that the appendix cited does not clarify anything.

Comment: Yes, this looks like the standard definition from Hartshorne and just about everywhere…

Comment: Thanks. I just found it weird that he felt the need to specify it in this convoluted fashion.

Comment: Does the book spend a fair bit of time dealing with presheaves, like to the point that presheaves of modules actually do arise in the exposition? That's the only reason I can think.

Comment: @TabesBridges No. However, the appendix treats the category of Quasi-Coherent modules in some detail.